# How to get toggled by a button from another component?

Tags: angular6

[Here is the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prmYK.jpg)

rigntsidenav.component.html

```
<div ng-sidebar-content>
    <button (click)="_toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
    <p>
        Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>
</div>
```

sidenav.service.ts

```
export class SidenavService {
public _opened: boolean = false;

public _toggleSidebar() {
this._opened = !this._opened;
}
constructor() { }
}
```

sidenav.component.html

```
<ng-sidebar [(opened)]="_opened" position="right">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
    <li>Menu Item</li>
  </ul>
</ng-sidebar>
```

How to toggle the sidenav with angular please help me

Comment: Can you show me project structure?

Comment: i added structure on the top

Comment: i saw, let try my anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sidenav.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SideNavService {
    public _opened = false;
    private sideNavSubject = new Subject<SideNavState>();
    sideNavState = this.sideNavSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    _show() {
        this.sideNavSubject.next(<SideNavState>{ _opened: true });
    }

    _hide() {
        this.sideNavSubject.next(<SideNavState>{ _opened: false });
    }
}

export interface SideNavState {
    _opened: boolean;
}
```

sidenav.component.ts

```
public _opened = false;

  constructor(private sideNavService: SideNavService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sideNavService.sideNavState.subscribe((state: SideNavState) => {
      this._opened = state._opened;
    });
  }
```

rigntsidenav.component.ts

```
constructor(private sideNavService: SideNavService) { }

  _toggleSidebar() {
    this.sideNavService._show();
  }
```

Remember add `SideNavService` to `app.module.ts`'s `providers`

Comment: Cannot find name 'SideNavState'

Comment: Cannot find name 'Subject'

Comment: import { Subject } from 'rxjs'; vscode not recommend for you?

Comment: What's problem?

Comment: All set and no error but the sidebar is not toggling

Comment: 'this._opened = state._opened;' does this work when you toggle on rightsidenav?

Comment: on debugging it, subscribe is the only problem

Comment: can you create stackblitz demo? It's work as well for me

Comment: Am sorry i cant do that